# Colon or comma: there are plenty of options [: , ] from X to Y

Tags: commas, colons

Is a comma or a colon the correct punctuation of the following sentence?

> There are plenty of meals from which to choose `///` from pasta to steak.

At the break between clauses, denoted by `///` it seems a colon is warranted as what comes before is a complete sentence, and what follows is explanatory details and not a complete sentence.

But a comma also makes sense, as it turns the last portion of the sentence into a modifier. But the modifier *from pasta to steak* would not be modifying the thing that comes immediately before, so it seems to violate that rule.

I see a similar question here: [Comma, colon or either in my text?](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/513256/edit) but that question's modifier clause does not contain the *from x to y* structure, and as such the answer to that question does not fully apply here. We would not replace the colon with *words such as namely, that is, as, for example, for instance, because, as follows,* because the word *from* would make that awkward: *options namely from pasta to steak*

Comment: Use a colon when providing a **list**; use a comma when following with a descriptive clause. *from ... to* is not a literal enumeration. "There are plenty of meals from which to choose, from pasta to steak."

Comment: Either is totally acceptable here (though the colon is considered perhaps a little old-fashioned in usages like this). A dash is less dated, but also less formal. 'From which to choose' also sounds perhaps a bit starchy, but a _from, from_ wouldn't be wonderful. 'There's a wide choice of meals:/–/,/... from pasta to steak' perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma.  It's no different than saying:

"From pasta to steak, there are plenty of meals from which to choose."

All you're doing is moving the prepositional phrase "from pasta to steak" to after the main clause.

To use a colon, you'd write something like:

"There are plenty of meals from which to choose: pasta, steak, and everything in between."